# unexpected end of pattern error with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21782101):

```
\<([\w]+)([^\>]*?)(([\s]*\/\>)|(\>((([^\<]*?|\<\!\-\-.*?\-\-\>)|(?R))*)\<\/\1[\s]*\>))
```

This regex matches any `html` code.

When I test it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3nf2g) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/A8PM12/1/) it works fine.

However when I test it with the following code in Python...

```
re.finditer('\<([\w]+)([^\>]*?)(([\s]*\/\>)|(\>((([^\<]*?|\<\!\-\-.*?\-\-\>)|(?R))*)\<\/\1[\s]*\>))', data):
```

... I get this error: `unexpected end of pattern`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `(?R)` is not a supported extension in the Python regex engine. Had you selected the Python engine in regex101 you'd have seen this earlier.

Comment: Is there any library that does? I thought I saw someone else using this in Python.

Comment: The linked post says "Not that I suggest using it, but..." while others correctly say that you should use an HTML parser and not regex.

Comment: If you press the `python` button on `regex101` it shows *"(? Incomplete group structure ) Incomplete group structure"* error.

Comment: [You cannot parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9478968)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern uses the `(?R)` recursive pattern modifier, which the Python `re` module does not support.

You'd have to install the [`regex` project](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead, which does support it.

Also, you probably want to use a `r` raw string literal, to make sure that the Python compiler doesn't interpret those backslashes directly (in this specific case it makes no difference):

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.compile(r'\<([\w]+)([^\>]*?)(([\s]*\/\>)|(\>((([^\<]*?|\<\!\-\-.*?\-\-\>)|(?R))*)\<\/\1[\s]*\>))')
regex.Regex('\\<([\\w]+)([^\\>]*?)(([\\s]*\\/\\>)|(\\>((([^\\<]*?|\\<\\!\\-\\-.*?\\-\\-\\>)|(?R))*)\\<\\/\\1[\\s]*\\>))', flags=regex.V0)
```

However, if you are going to install a 3rd-party library, install [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead, and use a proper HTML parser to parse HTML.

Comment: Great, that works. I didn't realize that `regex` was a different module. Thanks, I will accept in 8 minutes.